# Feedback op-amp voltage regulator help

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, zener, lm386

I have made a voltage regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fShc6C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And here is the zener circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPNvZB.png)</sup>

I have already tried to charge a device with this circuit,but it actually acts as an external battery.The device starts charging,but the battery's percentage doesn't go up,it remains the same.This must be happening because of low voltage or current supplied.What should I modify in order make the voltage regulator output more current and voltage(if necessary)?.The mentioned device charges at 5 V and 2000mA(charger's specifications).

Comment: I know the formula is on the net,but the problem is the zener circuit.I don't know the voltage set as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **a 9V battery will not output 2Amp**. This alkaline battery http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/522.pdf can give you 500mA but even then the rated capacity  is halved.

Next, **your "Zener circuit" will start conducting above 17V** (it starts conducting when Q2 base is 0.7V above ground, so when current through voltage divider reaches 0.7V/4.7kOhm=0.149mA ; this happens when input voltage is 114.7kOhm * 0.149mA = 17V). As-is it is equivalent to the voltage divider alone ; your + input is therefore about 0.2V below 9V. So the op-amp will be fully-on all the time.

Finally, did you use this particular amplifier? That's not an op-amp (gain is 20x) and the output is referenced to Vcc/2 (here to 4.5V). So, when inputs are equal the output voltage for your circuit is 3.8V.

I'd suggest you replace it with a proper op-amp, and choose it so that the output voltage can swing to at least 1V above output (that's 3V below rail) while delivering significant current. Also mind the input voltage range...

Or, if you're not after high precision (as your use of a non-temperature-compensated reference suggests) why not use directly your zener "circuit" and a pass transistor? Something like this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5IN9L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works because the zener steals the current from the transistor base as soon as the voltage is above the zener threshold, which is 0.7V above the output (because of the base-emitter voltage drop of the transistor).

Obviously for 2A you also need a beefier pass transistor, something like TIP41 instead of poor little BC547... It will have to dissipate max 2A*4V, that's 8W of power!! Then lower R3 to 47 Ohm.

Comment: Can you suggest another voltage reference?The output should be somewhere below 5 volts but still close to this value.I would appreciate if this reference would use transistors or diodes(no IC's).

Comment: You can use tl431, that's an IC but cheap, easy to find and in a transistor-like (TO92) package. But honestly, the voltage ref is the least of your problems, just adjust your resistor bridge and you'll have something working.

Comment: You should first adress the inadequate amplifier and battery ; then you can modify the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nicolas answer, the LM386 is definitely not suitable for this circuit, and nor is the 'zener'.

The circuit to implement the zener is not in regulation (as already noted) and is not actually doing anything for you. Either use a real zener at the voltage you need (which will be, by definition, below 9V) or come up with some other reference. These abound in single packages and may also be adjustable. The [venerable LM4040 series](http://www.ti.com/product/lm4040-n?keyMatch=lm4040&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything) comes to mind.

Then you can set the desired output voltage with the feedback resistors. A note on them - the ones you are using are low values and this is wasting output energy unnecessarily. I would normally be selecting parts in the 1k to 100k range for the divider parts.

The LM386 can have the gain set lower than nominal, but this should not be done **as it is internally compensated for a minimum gain of 9** (see [the LM386 datasheet page 3](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf). As a regulator loop of this type will have variable gain depending on the state of the load, you need to choose an amplifier that is stable at unity gain.

HTH